# GeoServer/QGIS : WMS Layer not displayed at right location

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I'm rather new in this field please forgive me if I dont use the right terms.

I have a Geoserver instance that I need to expose various WMS layers. I have multiple GeoTiff files, here is Water Bodies from Copernicus Land, the problem is the same with other sources I tried so far. When I open directly the tiff files with QGIS on my computer, they are displayed correctly:
[image: Expected visualisation]

I exposed the same file through Geoserver as a WMS layer, and when opening it with QGIS the map looks deformed/at the wrong location :
[image: WMS with QGIS]

I beleive I'm misunderstand something about CRS, although, when opening the layer with another tool it works well, I tried with wms-viewer-online.appspot.com and it looked just like the expected result.

I add here some of the layer configuration in Geoserver, maybe it's linked :
[image: Layer config]
The detected bounding box is correct, while the CRS is set to EPSG:4326 inside the tiff file. I tried to let the one detected by geoserver, forcing to declared, and tried both CRS in QGIS with the same results.

The bounding box displayed in QGIS after loading the layer is also 'reversed', but maybe that's not an issue
[image: bbox QGIS]

As requested, gdal.Info on one tiff returns :

```
'Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /###/20201001.tif
Size is 21636, 12600
Origin = (-7.579999999998790,41.199999999999733)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,0.000833333333333)
Metadata:
  flag_meanings=Sea Water No_data No_water
  flag_values=[0, 70, 251, 255]
  long_name=Water Body 100M
  standard_name=WB
  valid_range=[70, 70]
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND\nCorner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -7.5800000,  41.2000000) 
Lower Left  (  -7.5800000,  51.7000000) 
Upper Right (  10.4500000,  41.2000000) 
Lower Right (  10.4500000,  51.7000000) 
Center      (   1.4350000,  46.4500000) 
Band 1 Block=21636x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Water Body 100M'
```

Comment: please add the output of `gdalinfo` on one of your tiffs

Comment: @IanTurton added, this is the file when uploaded to geoserver

Comment: looks like an axis order flip, try apply a SRS to the tiff with `gdal_traslate -s_srs epsg:4326 ...` and then reload it

Comment: @IanTurton I ran `gdal.Translate('output.tif', ds, outputSRS="epsg:4326")` and got the following error : `RuntimeError: Failed to process SRS definition: epsg:4326`. I'm not very familiar with gdal, for info I already use `rioxarray.set_crs` method before saving the Tiff files

Comment: No idea how to do it in python - use the cli `gdalwarp` https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-s_srs

Comment: gdalinfo response look like no CRS is assigned to the tiff, which is I guess why GeoServer reports Native SRS as 404000

Comment: @nmtoken I used rioxarray to set the CRS before saving as a raster, I did the same operation with CAMS data and I see the CRS with gdal.Info, and geoserver does find the right CRS, but still the same issue when displaying with QGIS. Weirdest part is that other viewers than QGIS are reading the data from geoserver without issues, I then suppose it's a problem with QGIS rather than Geoserver